# how to make mac os stop auto minimizing app windows?

Tags: macos

I have Mac OS High Sierra. For as long as I can remember, Mac OS has always minimized applications that I keep in the background.  How do I make it stop doing this? I want the windows to stay open when I switch applications.

Answer (score 0):

All I can think is that someone put the machine in single application mode - which is by no means the default mode...

Open Terminal & type
`defaults read com.apple.dock single-app`
if the reply is TRUE or 1, then reset it with

`defaults write com.apple.dock single-app -bool false; killall Dock`

If the reply is FALSE or 0 then this was the wrong guess.

Comment: "The domain/default pair of (com.apple.dock, single-app) does not exist"

Comment: Might be worth running the `defaults write` line, wouldn't hurt anything; but if no joy then I'll leave this answer here just so no-one else is led down the same path. But maybe clarify, how exactly do you swap apps, Cmd/Tab, click in the dock, etc? Are any of these apps fullscreen?

Comment: I use cmd-tab a lot.  I never full-screen anything. I just find that randomly certain apps will be minimized. it's really annoying.

Comment: if it's 'random' it's more likely to be user error... e.g. alt/click on another app will hide the last app... Your original question made it appear to be systemic, all apps except the front-most were minimised.

Comment: if it's an error it's one I've been doing the past 3 years. I don't hold alt when I click app windows.